# How do I set the asp-route-id for an asp-action embedded in a CellTemplate of a Asp.Net Core DevExtreme DataGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, devextreme

I have an existing Asp.NetCore web app built using EFC written in C#. The webpages are built using Razor.
I am integrating the DevExpress DevExtreme DataGrid into a page.

**Here is my model class definition:**

```
public class Owner
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my page definition:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Owner>
@{ Layout = "_DevExtremeLayout"; ViewBag.Title = "All Owners";}

@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<SmartTracPoc.Models.Owner>()
    .DataSource(Model)
    .RemoteOperations(true)
    .AllowColumnReordering(true)
    .RowAlternationEnabled(true)
    .ShowBorders(true)
    .OnContentReady("contentReady")
    .Paging(p => p.PageSize(10))
    .Pager(p => p
        .ShowPageSizeSelector(true)
        .AllowedPageSizes(new[] { 10, 25, 50, 100 })
    )
    .SearchPanel(s => s
        .Visible(true)
        .HighlightCaseSensitive(true)
    )
    .GroupPanel(g => g.Visible(true))
    .Grouping(g => g.AutoExpandAll(false))
    .Columns(columns => {

        columns.AddFor(m => m.FirstName);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.LastName);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.PhoneNumber);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.OwnerId).CellTemplate(@<text> <a asp-action="UpdateOwner" asp-route-id="m => m.OwnerId"><img src="/icon/edit.png" /></a>);        
    })
)
```

**Here is the associated code snippet from the controller file:**

```
public class OwnerController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateOwner(Guid id)
    {
        Owner owner = new Owner();

        try
        {
            var requestString = ServerAddress + $"Owners/GetRecordById{id.ToString()}";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(requestString);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            owner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Owner>(responseString);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return View(owner);
    }
}
```

I'd like to use an anchor tag in a column definition to link to another page using the **OwnerId**.
I have tried to do this using a CellTemplate in the column definition:

```
columns.AddFor(m => m.OwnerId).CellTemplate(@<text> <a asp-action="UpdateOwner" asp-route-id="m => m.OwnerId"><img src="/icon/edit.png" /></a>);
```

Currently, the link fires the async method UpdateOwner() in the controller, but the id parameter is 0.

How do I set the asp-route-id for anchor tag in the CellTemplate definition?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the syntax on top of my head right now, but you can try this:

```
 columns.AddFor(m => m.OwnerId)
        .cellTemplate(@<text>
                      function(element, info) {
                         element.append('<a asp-action=\"UpdateOwner\" asp-route-id="' + info.ownerId + '\"><img src=\"/icon/edit.png\" /></a>')
                      }
                      </text>);
```

This isn't the best approach. If you want, you can register a click event or a button in the 'action column' that calls a JavaScript function.